# How to validate if an anchor tag was clicked before button click (Using javaScript)

Tags: javascript, anchor

Just wondering if anyone has done something like this in JavaScript before. 
I have a page with an anchor tag with a link and a button. What I was trying to do was display a message saying if the link was clicked or not after hitting the button.

This is what I had

```
 function validateLink() {
 var link = document.getElementById("vid");
        if (eval(link)) {
            if (link.clicked == true) {
                return true;
            } else {
                window.alert("You have not clicked the link");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is the anchor tag and the button

```
 <a href="https://www.joystiq.com/" target="_blank" id="vid">Here</a>  
 <button id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="validateLink()>
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Set an onclick on the anchor tag to set a global variable:  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Schlogen/3scnf/)

```
 a onclick="linkClicked = true;"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a global variable/flag and set default value of false. Set the value of the flag to true when hyperlink is clicked. When button is clicked read the value of the flag, if flag reads false, then hyperlink is not clicked, if flag reads true then hyperlink is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

```
var clicked = false;

function validateLink() {
     var link = document.getElementById("vid");
        if (eval(link)) {
            if (clicked == true) {
                return true;
            } else {
                window.alert("You have not clicked the link");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

HTML

```
<a href="https://www.joystiq.com/" target="_blank" id="vid" onclick="validateLink()">Here</a>
<button id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="clicked = true">Here</button>
```

Comment: I think you actually have this backwards. Unless I didn't understand it correctly, the onclick events should be reversed.

Comment: well i just fixed his code. If it doesn't fit his needs than he can swap the two onclick methods i guess